# Printing out duplicates python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cant spot all duplicates from the lists, after splitting them into numeric and non-numeric. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

The problem is that the below quote results if giving me two records instead of 3

```
for x in good:
 x = sorted(x)
  if good.count(x) > 1:
  good_dups.append(x)
```

Listy.txt - the external source of data

```
1,3,2,3
2,4,5,6
2,3,1
2,3,1
1,2,3
1,3,4,5
3,,4,5,6
1,  2,  3,  4. .,
123, 213, 12, ,
12. 122. 321  
13 32  167
```

Lists

```
wrong = []
good = []
good_dups = []
wrong_dups = []
```

Splitting the lists to the good and wrong by checking if they are numbers.

```
for n in content:
  n = n.split(',')
  if [k for k in n if not k.isdigit()]:
    wrong.append(n)
  else:
good.append(n)

print(("There are: "), len(good), ("error lines"))
for i, val in enumerate(good):
  print('Error Syntax', *val, sep=" ")
print()

print(("There are: "), len(good), ("correct lines"))
for i, val in enumerate(good):
  print('Error Syntax', *val, sep=" ")
print()
```

## Printing out the amount of duplicates in GOOD

```
for x in good:
  x = sorted(x)
  if good.count(x) > 1:
   good_dups.append(x)

print("There are: ", len(good_dups), " duplicates among ERROR lines:")
for i, val in enumerate(good_dups):
  print('Error Syntax', *val, sep=" ")
print()
```

## Printing out the amount of duplicates in WRONG

```
 for x in good:
 x = sorted(x)
 if good.count(x) > 2:
 good_dups.append(x)


print("There are: ", len(good_dups), " duplicates among CORRECT lines:")
for i, val in enumerate(good_dups):
  print('Error Syntax', *val, sep=" ")


print()
```

Comment: This looks like an [xy](http://xyproblem.info) problem. What is your actual expected output? there's probably a much shorter way to achieve it.

Comment: I want to print out 1,2,3  three times. Or state that there are 3 duplicates in good_dups.

Comment: What do you define as duplicates? Are 1, 2, 3 and 2, 3 1 duplicates?

Comment: Show desired output for a desired sample input please

Comment: So first I want to check if each row contains lists which are only numbers, coma seperated without special sing and split the into good and wrong. Then I want to find duplicates in those (good, wrong). Duplicates are considered:
2,3,1
2,3,1
1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why it does not work

The following code you wrote will not work.

```
good = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
good_dups = []

for x in good:
    x = sorted(x)
    if good.count(x) > 1:
        good_dups.append(x)

print(good_dups) # []
```

You are counting how many sorted copy of you list are in `good`, but if the original sublists are not sorted, `list.count` will not find them.

## Solution

What you might want to do is use sorted tuples as key to compare the sublists and keep track of them in a `dict` or a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

good = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 4]]
good_dups = defaultdict(list)

for x in good:
    good_dups[tuple(sorted(x))].append(x)

print(dict(good_dups)) # {(1, 2, 3): [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]], (2, 3, 4): [[2, 3, 4]]}
```

The duplicates are the entries which list has length two or more.